# Take information from web page and paste it into excell C# or Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, excel, automation, webautomation

Working in a huge virtual environment were we build dozens of servers a day. Right now we take a ticket from ServiceDesk copy important information over into a excel sheet then use that excel sheet to automate the build process. I want to automate the first part.

Give an array of tickets
Opens default service desk webpage
Searches ticket number (which opens it in another web page automatically)
Copy's information
Loop

I have experience with C# and JavaScript. I am looking for the best way to do the above task. What language, what extensions etc.

My main question is how do I get the information from this web page.

Thank you!

Comment: If the information you have in the browser is formatted in a `<table>` then copying and pasting into excel should hold it's formatting? If not then I guess you can output the information as `.csv`/`.tsv` and import.

Comment: Doy you have experience with Node.js?

Comment: Read about NodeJS(for server) or about NWJS(for desktop). You can do probably everything using these things.

Comment: Hey Andrew the information has to be put in specific rows in exell and the information on the web page is spread about. 
I;ve never heard of Node.js Ill take a look into it!

Comment: @ffalor i've updated my answer

Comment: Is it an existing excel sheet that you want to update? Since you are talking about specific rows.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg yes it is.

Comment: You're using CA Service Desk? That has a SOAP web service that may be a lot easier to use than trying to scrape the browser interface (especially given how many nested frames that thing uses!). I've got a 206-page PDF explaining everything about the web service. You might be able to find it by doing a web search for 'Unicenter Service Desk Web Services User Guide'.

Comment: I do not know if this is really an option for you, but you can consider to export a csv file that you use as datasheet for the existing excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Try excel parser/builder for Node.js - [node-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx).

Or you could use the native C# library from Microsoft. I think it has more functionality and is more productive than solution based on Node.js. Just take a look at [this](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm) article.